# Two finger scroll gesture with Tkinter scrolling

Tags: python, tkinter, gesture, touchpad

I have a Python program that uses Tkinter to display a scrollable window.  Is there any way to connect the two-finger swipe gesture on the touchpad to scrolling in this window?

Comment: If it's relevant, I am running Ubuntu with XFCE.

Comment: Do you have any try or source code that can share with us?

Comment: I suspect this is more up to the OS than tkinter. You likely need to configure Ubuntu to emit the scroll up/down action when a two finger gesture is used. Probably off-topic for this site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter - Scroll with mousepad / mouse gestures / two fingers scrolling in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75276563/tkinter-scroll-with-mousepad-mouse-gestures-two-fingers-scrolling-in-tkint)